# Create DMG on linux via SSH

Tags: backup, ssh, dmg

I would like to integrate my Time Machine backups with a manual script that will create a compressed and encrypted DMG image from some folders.

Reading about this issue, I *can* create a DMG, for instance

```
$ hdiutil create -verbose -encryption AES-256 -format UDBZ -stdinpass -srcfolder DIR FILE.DMG
```

The problem is that I don't have enough space to do that in the wild. So I was thinking about using my linux server as storage, but I don't know how.

> How can I create a DMG remotely via SSH on a linux server?

I have tried to see if `hdiutil` has a "dump to stdout" option, but I didn't see that, otherwise I'd be all set.

Note that I'd prefer just using macOS tools, without recompiling, if possible.

Comment: Did you try with a named pipe (and a process which transfer from the pipe to the Linux box over ssh)?

Comment: @nohillside No, I don't know how to use pipes except for something like `cat a.txt | grep something`...

Comment: Ok. Need to get back in front of a Mac first, may take a day or two. And it may not work...

Comment: Unfortunately `hdiutil` doesn't seem to allow to write to a named pipe, so this option doesn't seem to work

Comment: While it's not completely clear to me from your question as to what you're trying to do, I can tell you that I store my [TimeMachine back-ups on an NFS-mounted volume](https://smekkley.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/time-machine-via-nfs-on-mavericks/). So that's an option if your linux server is on your local network. If it _has_ to be over ssh, then look into sshfs (available via brew) which can be used to mount remote filesystems over ssh.